# Probability answer verification for normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Question: The mean height of a group of 200 people is 164cm with a standard deviation of 6cm.
Assuming the heights are normally distributed find the probability of a person’s height
being:

(i) less than 164cm
(ii) more than 166cm
(iii) greater than 176cm

Answers:
(i)  0.5
(ii) 0.3707
(iii)0.0228

Here are my workings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXlg.jpg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The text after "question:" is the question, i gave my answers afterwards and was hoping someone could verify them. I can't show my workings because there's a limit on image file sizes here.

Comment: It would be better if you showed us how you´ve obtained these results.

Comment: added image with workings.

Comment: At **(iii)** I get $\Phi(2)=0.97725$ (i) and (ii) are correct.

Comment: Could you show your workings so we can compare? Nevermind, you're correct. It's 1-0.9772=0.0228

Comment: You are fine now?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You´re welcome, Alan.